# Why is the last number getting logged as undefined in this for loop?

Tags: javascript

It always leaves the last element as undefined. Am I not incrementing correctly?

```js
function loopASequenceAgain(start, end) {
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

console.log(loopASequenceAgain(2, 5));
// console output:
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

Comment: `loopASequenceAgain` doesn't return anything, so it will return undefined. So it should log undefined after all the numbers. This is expected

Comment: `loopASequenceAgain` doesn't return anything. `console.log(loopASequenceAgain(` doesn't make any sense

Comment: but im logging the element at the end of the for loop

Comment: You don't even need the last `console.log`, You can just call the function and see the desired result.

Comment: And it isn't logging 5 because you used `<` instead of `<=` so the loop stops before it gets to that point.